# Xcode 4 Orientation to Landscape grayed out

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xcode4, orientation, xib, landscape

I'm trying to create an ipad app in xcode 4 that supports ONLY landscape view. By default the MainWindow.xib file displays the interface in Portrait mode. I cannot change it to landscape mode because the option is grayed out.

If I create a UIViewController subclass, I'm able to rotate that new view to landscape. Just not the original MainWindow.xib viewcontroller.

The way I've been able to work around this, is to create a second view controller and set that to landscape as the option is not grayed out on this one. Then I create a button on the first view controller that switches to the second one where I place all my objects.

There has to be an easier way to have the main viewcontroller "MainWindow.xib" appear in the interface builder as Landscape. I just can't figure it out. Do I really a second view to have a landscape xib to create objects on? If so, how can I have that second view be the main view so that I don't need a button to switch to it?

I'm totally new to Xcode and IOS development, so please forgive my noobness.

Comment: As soon as I posted this, I went to take a screenshot of the box being grayed out... But then I figured it out! This is what I did.. http://i.imgur.com/azznq.jpg

I hope this helps other noobs who were told by others where to find the orientation setting, even though they said the option was grayed out. <3